# Finding the number of common elements between two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, element

I need a way to find how many common elements in between two arrays.

Suppose that I have:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
b = {2,4,6,8,10}
```

So the result would be 4.

I need it to be effective with very large array like arrays of length 1300000. I have tried the intersect method but it gave me a wrong number such as 256 or 11 and tried with method Zip but it's too slow.

Comment: how did you use Intersect?

Comment: Don't think that Intersect does not work...

Comment: Did you use `a.Intersect(b).Count()`?

Comment: Can you post some code - what you already have / have tried?

Comment: @Douglas yes as i said i my questio  it gave me wrong number

Comment: `int equalElements = ival.Zip(jval, (iv, jv) => iv == jv).Count(eq => eq);` while ival , jval are arrays of type byte @Unihedron

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano `ival.Intersect(jval).Count();`  **ival** and **jval** are arrays

Comment: ` byte[] ival=mydictionary.Values.ToArray()[i];
  byte[] jval=mydictionary.Values.ToArray()[j];
  var cou =ival.Intersect(jval).Count();`
note that ival and jval have length of 1300000 and have more than 50000 at least common element ,, i and j are for loop variables

Comment: You're calling ToArray() in every loop. Every call will copy all the items into a new array. Since the Dictionary is very large, it's better to call it just once and loop through the array. This probably won't solve your problem though, since ToArray should produce the same array every time if nothing has changed inside the Dictionary. Are you adding or removing items inside the loop?

Comment: so what do you suggest to compare the values of each dictionary ?
note that the loop is very important and i can't reomve it

Comment: I just meant to create one array instead of a new one every loop: var array = mydictionary.Values.ToArray(); and then use the array variable in the loop: byte[] ival = array[i]; byte[] jval = array[j];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Intersect`

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List<int> b = new List<int>{2,4,6,8,10} ;

int CommonNumber = a.Intersect(b).Count();
```

Comment: did you mean to convert arrays to List<int>

Comment: Yes that's it just put your number at List<int>

Comment: You don't have to put them in a List. An array works fine too. So will anything else that inherits IEnumerable.

Comment: Yes that's right he can work with array since they inherit from IEnumerable